# Put a variable in image path JavaFX

Tags: javafx

i'm a beginner in javaFX and have a probleme with imageview , i want to generate an image with a variable in the path like this it worked on swing but not on javaFx here is the code and errors :

```
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

    com1.getItems().addAll("Francais","anglais","JEE","SOA","Math");
    com2.getItems().addAll("LFI1","LFI2","LFM2","PREPA","LFI3");

}    
void onShow(ActionEvent event) {

   String seance = com1.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem(); //ComboBox with Strings
    Image qr= new Image("Qrimages/"+seance+".jpg"); 
    image.setImage(qr);

}
```

it say's :

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URL: Invalid URL or resource not found
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URL or resource not found
```

i tried to change the variable with an existing name and it works but i need to get this path form static to dynamique

Comment: A simple way to solve this would be to put your images in teh default package and then just refer to your images by name

Comment: The parameter for the `Image` constructor is an URL. (*"Invalid URL or resource not found"* thrown from the `Image` constructor is a strong indicator for this.) You're missing the protocol however. Without knowlege about where the images are stored, it's impossible to tell you how to get the correct urls though. Also if you're able to use the images with "static" paths you most likely have an typo somewhere. Passing the same string to the image constructor should not make a difference, whether you got the string by using a literal string or by concatenating some strings.

Comment: SteelToe the problème is that the image will be created when the programe is running and the name of the image dépends of whatever the user has selected in the combobox

Comment: Fabian ok i will try